# NumberPlane grid not showing ManimGL Scene

Tags: manim

I recently started using ManimGL version 1.6.1
When I ran the "OpeningManimExample" scene from the example_scenes.py,
there should be a grid in the scene. But it shows only the labels, there are no grid lines.

```
class OpeningManimExample(Scene):
def construct(self):
    intro_words = Text("""
        The original motivation for manim was to
        better illustrate mathematical functions
        as transformations.
    """)
    intro_words.to_edge(UP)

    self.play(Write(intro_words))
    self.wait(2)

    # Linear transform
    grid = NumberPlane((-10, 10), (-5, 5))
    matrix = [[1, 1], [0, 1]]
    linear_transform_words = VGroup(
        Text("This is what the matrix"),
        IntegerMatrix(matrix, include_background_rectangle=True),
        Text("looks like")
    )
    linear_transform_words.arrange(RIGHT)
    linear_transform_words.to_edge(UP)
    linear_transform_words.set_stroke(BLACK, 10, background=True)

    self.play(
        ShowCreation(grid),
        FadeTransform(intro_words, linear_transform_words)
    )
    self.wait()
    self.play(grid.animate.apply_matrix(matrix), run_time=3)
    self.wait()

    # Complex map
    c_grid = ComplexPlane()
    moving_c_grid = c_grid.copy()
    moving_c_grid.prepare_for_nonlinear_transform()
    c_grid.set_stroke(BLUE_E, 1)
    c_grid.add_coordinate_labels(font_size=24)
    complex_map_words = TexText("""
        Or thinking of the plane as $\\mathds{C}$,\\\\
        this is the map $z \\rightarrow z^2$
    """)
    complex_map_words.to_corner(UR)
    complex_map_words.set_stroke(BLACK, 5, background=True)

    self.play(
        FadeOut(grid),
        Write(c_grid, run_time=3),
        FadeIn(moving_c_grid),
        FadeTransform(linear_transform_words, complex_map_words),
    )
    self.wait()
    self.play(
        moving_c_grid.animate.apply_complex_function(lambda z: z**2),
        run_time=6,
    )
    self.wait(2)
```

Output is like this:
[OpeningManimExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpJbV.png)

I also found similar problem in Flash, FlashAround animations.

Comment: Same problem here, has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: Did any one found solution?

Comment: I've found the solution. See this: [link](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/discussions/1546)